# qt out of memory while using the Eigen

Tags: c++, qt, out-of-memory, eigen

I have created a class:

```
class MyMatrix
{
public:
    MyMatrix();
    MyMatrix(const cv::Mat& m);
    MyMatrix operator -(const MyMatrix mm);
    MatrixXf* operator []  (int n ) const;

    int getChannel () ;
    MatrixXf* getChannelElem(int channel)const;
    cv::Mat convertToMat()const;
    ~MyMatrix();
private :
    MatrixXf* image[MAXCHANNEL];
    int channelOfImage;
};
```

but the compiler reported that out of memory allocating 168729 bytes. The system is windows 7 64bit ,version of qt is Qt 5.2.1 version of eigen is Eigen3.2.1 . Does anyone know the reason?thank you!!

Comment: Uh, so what ran out of memory here, compiler or your program? With this little info it's going to be hard to answer your question.

Comment: The compiler ran out of memory.I have tested the program without this class,no problems come up.I store the image data with this class.Several channels of the image are stored in MatrixXf* image[MAXCHANNEL]. I have annotated all the implements of the class,but the compiler still runs out of memory.

Comment: I have solved the problem by deleting the header that #include <QtGui>. But i  still don't know the reason.